# VirtualBox RAM memory issue

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, virtualbox, kubuntu

Host PC: Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64
Processor: 3.4 GHz Intel Core i3-4130
RAM: 4 GB DDR3

I'm creating a virtual PC which will run Kubuntu 14.04 LTS. I lost the ISO but have a bootable USB stick (identified by Windows as Disk 1, no problem here). This is what I did:

1. Opened up CMD as admin, cd to `Oracle\VirtualBox` and ran this command:

`VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename H:\Kubuntu.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1`

This creates a VMDK hard disk which boots from the USB drive.

2. Opened VirtualBox as admin (a must to use that VMDK file).
3. Created new VM. 64-bit Ubuntu (Linux). 1.5 GB RAM, 8 GB Disk Memory, 2 Cores.
4. The VM boots up. I see this message but no errors here, it boots up the installer after this:

[image: bootupmsg]

5. Setup comes up. RAM is hitting 2.6 GB right now-looks like I may run out of memory:

[image: vminstallerstarts]

6. Bah! I get this nagging error.

[image: vmerror]

I believe this may be due to lack of memory. So I shut down the VM, scale the memory down to 512 MB.

[image: vmreconfig]

7. Again! And  the "Try Kubuntu" button hasn't even shown up. Do note, RAM usage has gone down from 2.5 GB to 2.2 GB.

[image: vmyudodis]

**Help please!**

Comment: "*I believe this may be due to lack of memory.*" Okay, that's weird.

Comment: Now that the issue is fixed, and I've monitored the RAM usage while Kubuntu was doing heavy stuff, I feel like an idiot now writing that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can't read properly from the flash drive despite administrator access. Found the ISO and reinstalled it with initial VM specs. All is well now.